# Each SQL select Statement result in a Text format

Tags: sql-server

I have select statement that result in thousands of rows.

```
 SELECT l.account_reference_no as arn, 
       Coalesce(l.preApprovalNo,0) as app_no, 
       Coalesce(Dateadd(SECOND, l.time_stamp_seconds, l.time_stamp_date), '1900-01-01 00:00:00') as prosp_date, 
       l.combined_name as name, 
       status    FROM   Link_LIST as l
```

Some sample result is given  here

```
arn         app_no      prosp_date              name                                                                                                  status
----------- ----------- ----------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------
100110018   0           1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 WG & SM Davis                                                                                         INACTIVE
100110026   0           1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 Mrs LM Johnston                                                                                       INACTIVE
100110034   0           1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 P & V Bartlett & Giles                                                                                INACTIVE
100110042   0           1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 Mr D & Ms L Setters & Kirley                                                                          INACTIVE
100110059   0           1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 CT & DE West                                                                                          INACTIVE
100110067   0           1900-01-01 00:00:00.000                                                                                                       INACTIVE
100110075   0           1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 A & L O'Bree                                                                                          INACTIVE
100110091   0           1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 RJ & LE Schaeche & Kenny                                                                              INACTIVE
```

I am looking for a solution to get the output as  following format . This is because , i have to insert this result in a different database, that is on another system

```
insert into #new_arn (arn, app_no, prosp_date, name, status) values (402470011,0, '01/Jan/1900 00:00:00','Mr A Bicket','Inactive')
insert into #new_arn (arn, app_no, prosp_date, name, status) values (402470037,0, '01/Jan/1900 00:00:00','Ms K Edwards','Inactive')
insert into #new_arn (arn, app_no, prosp_date, name, status) values (402470052,0, '01/Jan/1900 00:00:00','Ms BJ Sippel','Inactive')
insert into #new_arn (arn, app_no, prosp_date, name, status) values (402470110,0, '01/Jan/1900 00:00:00','Mr GA & Mrs S Wilson','Inactive')
insert into #new_arn (arn, app_no, prosp_date, name, status) values (402470128,0, '01/Jan/1900 00:00:00','r M & Ms S Holland','Inactive')
insert into #new_arn (arn, app_no, prosp_date, name, status) values (402470144,0, '01/Jan/1900 00:00:00','Mr M Hanns','Inactive')
```

Is there a way to generate this using MSSQL management studio

Comment: Modify your select statement to produce the desired output by concatenating the values together with the extra strings required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the support.   this is the final solution, in case some one needs for future reference

```
SELECT CONCAT('insert into #new_arn (arn, app_no, prosp_date, name, status) values (', l.account_reference_no,',',Coalesce(l.preApprovalNo,0),',''',Coalesce(Dateadd(SECOND, l.time_stamp_seconds, l.time_stamp_date), '1900-01-01 00:00:00'),''', ''',l.combined_name,''',''',status,''')') FROM   Link_LIST as l
```

Answer (score 2):

try the following:

```
select 'insert into #new_arn (arn, app_no, prosp_date, name, status) values ( ' + convert(varchar(max), l.account_reference_no) + ','+  convert(varchar(max), Coalesce(l.preApprovalNo,0)) 
       + ',''' + Coalesce(Dateadd(SECOND, l.time_stamp_seconds, l.time_stamp_date), '1900-01-01 00:00:00') + ''',''' +  l.combined_name + ''',' + '''Inactive''' from [dbo].[sourceTable]
```

hit `CTRL+T` (text output) and then `CTRL+E` (execute query)

Please format the date as per your requirement.